# Using hot reload from Chrome extension (React)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, build, hotdeploy

I'm using React to build a Chrome extension (using this [boilerplate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chrome-extension-boilerplate))

Currently, I need to manually build it every time to see the changes in the extension.
What changes do I need to do in package.json to have 'hot deployment'
(I need the files in the disk to be changed automatically)

Thanks

Comment: The README of that repository states that `This boilerplate uses Webpack and react-transform, and use Redux. You can hot reload by editing related files of Popup & Window & Inject page`. It doesn't work?

Comment: While running 'npm run dev' I can see it recompiles when I do changes but in Chrome I do not see changes in the extension itself until I run 'npm run build'